# Adding a value in two different tables in my create controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a Create controller that creates a record in one table [Kursus_kursist] using db.Add, dbSaveChanges().
I need to create a record in another table [jobcoach] based on one of the values (kursus_kursist_id which is an int), but I don't know how to pass the value.

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "kursus_kursist_id,kursist_id,status, jc")] kursus_kursist kursus_kursist)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.kursus_kursist.Add(kursus_kursist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.jobcoach.Add(/*I THINK THE KURSUS_KURSIST_ID NEEDS TO GO HERE*/);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("../kursister/Index");
        }
```

I've been able to create a record in both the usus_kursist and jobcoach tables, but in the jobcoach table I don't get the kursus_kursist_id - so basically an empty record (aside from the PK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add to the database and save, that entity becomes tracked. The tracked entity have an assigned Id.

```
var myEntity = new SomeEntity(){
   Name="Test",
   CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
}

dbContext.MyEntities.Add(myEntity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine(myEntity.Id);
```

This will give you the proper Id EF assigned your entity.
If JobCoach is connected you could also add them in their existing relation.

```
var myEntity = new SomeEntity(){
       Name="Test",
       CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
       MyChildObject = new ChildObject(){
           Name="Something else",
           CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
    }

    dbContext.MyEntities.Add(myEntity);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();        

    Console.WriteLine(myEntity.MyChildObject.Id);
```

So in your case you should be able to use your first kursist_thingie.Id after you saved that entity. Assign JobCoach.KursistId = kursist_thingie.Id or however you please.

Hope it helps!